# who to get CDATA in webservice reponse from hybris 2011

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to get XML CDATA in webservice response of Hybris API's in Hybris CX 2011.

I also tried adding them as a string before setting even with escape characters but no use because when I curl them in "application/xml" `<![CDATA[name]]>` is read as `&lt;![CDATA[name]]&gt;` and all this is happening in /V2.

Comment: You did not format correctly your question, please check now whether it's better, and please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you please add  sample request and expected result